# Get complete URL which contains "#"

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

I am sending two URLs as URL parameter in the request URL. 
Something like :

```
http:///router.jsp?app1=http://<h1>.com/search=%22INC_CAL_1000009%22&app2=http://host.com:<port>/ux/ang-app/#/search/REQ_ID_1000009/
```

One is a normal jsp-servlet application and other one is an Angular based version of the same application.

As you can see the URL of the angular based application is something like 
`http://host.com:<port>/ux/ang-app/#/search/REQ_ID_1000009/` when I try to extract it using `getQueryString` the last part `search/REQ_ID_1000009/` is not being captured.

Can some please suggest the correct approach?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Are you doing that in a JSP or in a servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Java:

```
String app1= "http://.com/search=\"INC_CAL_1000009\"";
String app2 = "http://host.com:/ux/ang-app/#/search/REQ_ID_1000009/";
String url = "http:///router.jsp"
        + "?app1=" + URLEncoder.encode(app1, "UTF-8")
        + "&app2=" + URLEncoder.encode(app2, "UTF-8");
```

in JSP/JSTL:

```
<c:url value="http:///router.jsp">
    <c:param name="app1" value="${app1}"/>
    <c:param name="app2" value="${app2}"/>
</c:url>
```

(assuming the attributes app1 and app2 are set with the correct value)